# How to get queryset of manytomanyfiled through foreignkey(model only has 2 field)

Tags: django, python-3.x, filter, many-to-many, django-queryset

how to queryset manytomanyfiled through a foreignkey, my model only has 2 field as below:

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User_B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    project_c = models.ManyToManyField(Project_C, related_name="+", blank=True)
```

user_b has many project_c as below, I want to get the queryset of the list of project_c of current user_b:

```
id project_c_id
1   1
2   2    
3   3
4   4 
..  ..
..  ..
```

Thanks so much, really appreciate for any advice!!!

Comment: Provide a sample query you want to resolve.

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter? You want `Model_A`s that satisfy both a condition on `b` and `c`? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, I already updated my question, I want to get the queryset(a list) of manytomanyfield Project_C, different user(current user) has his own list......Please forgive my poor English and so newbin in Django and python.....

Comment: So you want all `Project_C`s for which the corresponding `Model_A` has as `user_b` a certain user?

Comment: Model_A.objects.filter(user_b__pk=pk) or Model_A.objects.filter(user_b__pk__in=[pk1, pk2, pk3]) maybe works but if you wan't to make a relation between project_c and user_b maybe it will be good to do it inside these models

Comment: Yes, Willem, I believe Django or Python can achieve it, but I don't know how to do it, could you please give me a hand? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to related_name between Model_A and Project_C as below:

```
class Model_A(models.Model):
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User_B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    project_c = models.ManyToManyField(Project_C, related_name="projects", blank=True)
```

Then query it by below code:

```
Project_C.objects.filter(permits__user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: It's more overall, I have to revise and set this answer as correct answer, to let more newbies learn.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the `Model_A` objects filtered by `user` an return only their `project_c` values.

```
Model_A.objects.filter(user_b__id=user_id).values_list('project_c')
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto, I use Project_C.objects.filter(model_a__user=someuser) by Willem provided, it works, Thank you all the same for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to obtain a queryset that contains `Project_C` instances for which the `user` of a corresponding `Model_A` is a specific user.

We can query this with:

```
Project_C.objects.filter(model_a__user=someuser)
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much for your prompt answer, Thanks again Willem

Answer (score 1):

model = Model_A.objects.get(user_b=user) 
projects = Project_c.objects.filter(model_a_set__contains=model)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I use Project_C.objects.filter(model_a__user=someuser) by Willem provided, it works, Thank you all the same for your answer.